# Python "import request" returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having allot of trouble getting python 2.7.5 to work on my CentOS7 server. Testing prints is not an issue but when I'm trying to import requests it breaks. I don't understand te error_log. I don't know what to do now. Please help :)

Yes requests is installed, I triple checked.

My code:

```
import requests
```

Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

Error_log:

```
    [Mon Jan 21 20:11:54.179538 2019] [:error] [pid 16293] [client 84.85.100.198:32770] PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler: Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Mon Jan 21 20:11:54.179578 2019] [:error] [pid 16293] [client 84.85.100.198:32770] PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 398, in HandlerDispatch\n    result = obj(req)
    [Mon Jan 21 20:11:54.179586 2019] [:error] [pid 16293] [client 84.85.100.198:32770] PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/cgihandler.py", line 96, in handler\n    imp.load_module(module_name, fd, path, desc)
    [Mon Jan 21 20:11:54.179592 2019] [:error] [pid 16293] [client 84.85.100.198:32770] PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler:   File "/var/www/vhosts/vps-139083-2773.hosted.at.hostnet.nl/regt/test.py", line 23, in <module>\n    import requests
    [Mon Jan 21 20:11:54.179598 2019] [:error] [pid 16293] [client 84.85.100.198:32770] PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>\n    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
    [Mon Jan 21 20:11:54.179605 2019] [:error] [pid 16293] [client 84.85.100.198:32770] PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 61, in load_module\n    if name in sys.modules:
    [Mon Jan 21 20:11:54.179628 2019] [:error] [pid 16293] [client 84.85.100.198:32770] PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'
```

Comment: Do you have a `requests.py` in that same folder? It appears to be running it.

Comment: In the same folder as what?

Comment: In your `pwd` when you run the script that's calling `import requests`.

Comment: /var/www/vhosts/vps-139083-2773.hosted.at.hostnet.nl/regt/test.py

That is the file containing: "import requests".

no reqeusts.py in that dir, Is that the problem?

Comment: Does the following file exist and does the user apache is running over have permissions for /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py?

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py YES but its from 2014 and not under requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using an older version of requests.

Unless you have a reason not to, try to upgrade requests to latest:

```
$ pip install --upgrade requests
```

Comment: [root@re packages]# pip install --upgrade requests :

Cannot uninstall 'requests'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall. From one problem to another

Comment: Which distribution of Linux are you using? I would recommend that you uninstall the version of requests that was installed via your package manager, and instead install it via pip. Example, $ apt-get purge python-requests

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Benton Snyder i fixed the problem.

`pip install --upgrade requests` din't work but i had to manualy remove the requests dir and then restart my server.

After that i reinstalled via `pip install requests`